# xUnit - Group assertion into a method to reuse

Tags: xunit

I have a scenario where the assertion is the same for all the tests (verify the client call correct Uri, correct httpMethod).

I wanted to group the two assertions into a method and reuse it but it does not seem to work.

```cs
private void VerifyHttpMethodAndUri(HttpMethod expectedMethod, string expectedUri)
{
    _httpMessageHandler.Request.Method.Should().Be(expectedMethod);
    _httpMessageHandler.Request.RequestUri?.AbsolutePath.Should().Be(expectedUri);
}
```

Anyone who has done it please give me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it back ..... it works

Comment: If you were able to get it working, please post a minimum working code as a solution to your question here, so that it helps others as well in case they come looking for a solution.

Comment: private void VerifyHttpMethodAndUri(HttpMethod expectedMethod, string expectedUri)
{
           _httpMessageHandler.Request.Method.Should().Be(expectedMethod);
            
           _httpMessageHandler.Request.RequestUri?.AbsolutePath.Should().Be(expectedUri);
 }

Comment: sorry not have time to google formatting it